# Indefinite Integral -- Last step is a duzzy

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int \frac{x-x^2}{2(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x$$

1. I pull the $\frac{1}{2}$ out to get $\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x-x^2}{x+1}\mathrm{d}x$
2. I realize this can be done with partial fractions; however, since the degree of the numerator is greater than the degree of the denominator, I do long division.
3. I get $\frac{1}{2}\frac{-x+2-2}{x+1}$
4. Distribute the $\frac{1}{2}$ and get:  -x/2 +1 -1/(x+1) dx
5. Use substitution for the last piece and get:
   -ln(x+1) +x -1/4x^2 +C

The book as well as online wolfram integrator gets the same answer PLUS 5/4!!!!! Says, "for restricted values of x".  ?????

Stuck on figuring out how they get this 5/4 value.  What am I not seeing?

I can't figure out where the 5/4 comes from

Comment: This is indefinite integration, so the $5/4$ can be absorbed into the arbitrary constant ($+C$). Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you , thank you.  I just wrapped around the axle for nothing.  Wolfram had 5/4 +C.  I now see that both of them are constants so could be C prime I guess.  I just couldn't figure out why or where they obtained the 5/4.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeking the antiderivative $-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2-x}{x+1}dx. $ Applying long division gets \begin{align*}-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2-x}{x+1}dx &= -\frac{1}{2}\int  \left( x - 2 + \frac{2}{x+1}\right)dx \\ &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2-2x+2\ln\left|x+1\right| \right)+C\end{align*} (don't forget the absolute value sign).

As Adriano mentioned, the $\frac{5}{4}$ that Wolfram obtained is irrelevant, since $C$ in the case of indefinite integration can be any constant, hence it can 
"absorb" $\frac{5}{4}$ (just think of any constant and subtract $\frac{5}{4}$ from it; the equation is still just as valid, and it'll "cross out" the $\frac{5}{4}$ Wolfram obtained). I am not sure how Wolfram got that value, and would also be curious to know why it is there.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I wonder too